# How to use images in a selection form (for example checkboxes) in elgg

Tags: image, forms, selection, elgg

How could I use images in a selection form like this in elgg? Here's the example image of what I want to do:

[image]

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can create checkboxes with plain HTML or use the [input/checkbox](https://github.com/Elgg/Elgg/blob/1.8/views/default/input/checkbox.php) or [input/checkboxes](https://github.com/Elgg/Elgg/blob/1.8/views/default/input/checkboxes.php) views to generate it for you. All of those let you use arbitrary HTML for the label, so you can use an IMG element.